# Stream processing mixed sync and async items

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a list of objects to process. Some can be processed immediately, but others need to be processed by first fetching a URL. The organization looks something like:

```py
processed_items = []
for item in list:

    if url := item.get('location'):
        fetched_item = fetch_item_from(url)
        processed_item = process(fetched_item)

    else:
        processed_item = process(item)

    if processed_item:
        processed_items.append(processed_item)
```

The problem is that there are so many items that the only way to handle this in a memory efficient way is to process these files as they come in. On the other hand, doing them sequentially like this takes forever -- it's much more efficient to make the network requests asynchronously.

In theory, you could save all the items with URLs, then fetch them all at once using tasks and `asyncio.gather`. I have actually done this and it works. But this list of unfetched items can quickly eat up your memory, since the items are being streamed in, and making a ton of network requests all at once can make the server mad.

I think I'm looking for a result that leaves me with an array like

```py
processed_items = [1, 2, <awaitable>, 3, <awaitable>, ...]
```

which I can then await the result of.

Is this the right approach? And if so, what's this design pattern called? Any first steps?

Comment: To avoid making the server mad and also to avoid eating up your memory, why not divide the work into chunks and process them one chunk at a time?

Comment: @PaulCornelius the way I've described solves those problems. You're right that I could chunk the requests to the server, or slow them down by limiting the number of simultaneous connections (this is what we're doing now), but this is a slow solution, since there can be tens of thousands of little micro-files to fetch. If we spread out the fetches by just fetching the URLs as needed, we don't need to do this chunking.

Comment: If you don't mind humoring me with some more questions, if you're already pushing the server to its limit, how can the process possibly go any faster?  Isn't that always going to be a physical bottleneck?  If it's not, then what is the bottleneck?

Comment: @PaulCornelius no problem at all. It's the difference between processing `[item, item, item, <remote item>, item, item...]` vs `[item, item, ..., <remote item>, <remote item>, <remote item>]`. Doing it the second way (sending all the remote requests at once) creates a flood of requests, whereas processing them as they come in spreads those requests out.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute your code above in an asynchronous function - in a way that each item is processed in a separate task, and wrap your "fetch_item_from" function in an async function that uses an [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore) to limit the number of parallel requests to one you find optimal - be it 7, 10, 50 or 100.

If the rest of your processing is just CPU intensive you won't need any other async features there.

Actually, if your `fetch_item_from" is not async itself, you can simply do "run_in_executor" - and the nature of the process.future.Executor itself will limit the amount of concurrent requests, without the need to use a Semaphore are all.

```
 import asyncio

MAXREQUESTS = 20

# Use this part if your original `fetch_item_from` is synchronous:

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(MAXREQUESTS)
async def fetch_item_from_with_executor(url):
    asyncio.get_running_loop()
    # This is automatically limited to the number of workers in the executor
    return await asyncio.run_in_executor(executor, fetch_item_from, url)
    
    
# Use this part if fetch_item_from is asynchronous itself
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(MAXREQUESTS)
async def fetch_item_from_async(url):
    with semaphore:
        return await fetch_item_from(url)

# common code:

async def process_item(item):
    if url := item.get('location'):
        item = await fetch_item_from_executor(url) # / fetch_item_from_async
    return process(item)

    
async def main(list_):

    pending_list = [asyncio.create_task(item) for item in list_]
    processed_items = [] 
    while pending_list:
        # The timeout=10 bellow is optional, and will return the control
        # here with the already completed tasks each 10 seconds: 
        # this way you can print some progress indicator to see how 
        # things are going - or even improve the code so that  
        # finished tasks are yielded earlier to be consumed by the callers of "main"
        # in parallel
        # if the timeout argument is omitted, all items are processed in a single batch.
        done, pending_list = await asyncio.wait(pending_list, timeout=10)
        processed_items.extend(done)  # the filter builtin will add just 
            
    # retrieve the results from each task and filter out the falsy (None?) ones:
    return [result for item in processed_items if (result:=item.result())]


list_= ...

processed_items = asyncio.run(main(list_))
```

(missing above is any error handling - if either `fetch_item_from` or `process` can raise any exception, you have to unfold the list-comprehension which calls `.result()` in each task blindly to
separate the ones that raised from the ones that completed sucessfully)